# Add column into Archive Manager interface

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I've just made a mistake and I have removed the **'Name'** column from the Archive Manager program interface. Here is the actual interface:

[image]

Now, I can't see the '**Name**' column. I've tried to modify everything in the options but I couldn't get it back.

How do I restore the 'Name' column? If the program has a config file, where can I find it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No, really I don't know... either way the problem has been fixed. The column was hidden. I uninstalled the whole package and re installed and then I could move the first "name" header.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the column title bar (where is says Tamaño, Tipo, Modificado) a menu should pop up. From the menu you can tick the columns you want to see in the interface. Tick the Name column and your problem should be solved.

Comment: No menu is displayed when I right click on the title bar. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed. The column was hidden.

I uninstalled the whole package and re installed and then I could move the first "name" header.